# How can I tell pyreverse to include classes within modules within packages?

Tags: python, uml, pylint, class-diagram, pyreverse

I have this folder structure:

```
.
└── src
    ├── a
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── a.py
    │   └── b.py
    └── main.py
```

Contents of a/a.py:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'a'
```

Contents of a/b.py

```
from a.a import A


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'b'
```

Conents of main.py:

```
from a.a import A
from a.b import B

print(A().name)
print(B().name)
```

As you can see, class B inherits from class A

I have confirmed that the program works as expected, so there are no errors in the code

I wish to run something along the lines of: `pyreverse src/**/* -o png` and generate a UML diagram showing me that class B inherits from class A (I have a bigger project with many more directories, hence the reason for the `**/*` part).

However, what I am getting at the moment is this:

[image]

The expected would be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question: the answer was to simply cd to src/, or do this:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}/src"
```