# pyreverse not connecting classes in UML class diagram

Tags: python, uml, class-diagram, pyreverse

I'm trying to create a UML diagram of a python project that shows inheritance relationships between classes using pyreverse.

Here's a small example to reproduce

`Foo.py`:

```
class Foo():
    def print_foo(self):
        print("hi")
```

`Bar.py`:

```
from Foo import Foo

class Bar(Foo):
    pass
```

`__init__.py`: empty

To generate the diagram, I'm running `pyreverse -ASmy -o png .`

The resulting diagrams look like this:

`classes.png`:

[image: Class diagram]

`packages.png`:

[image: Package diagram]

I would expect the class diagram to show an arrow connecting the two classes, but I can't figure out what I'm missing. Any ideas what's wrong here?

Output of `pylint --version`:

```
pylint 2.14.5
astroid 2.12.10
Python 3.10.5 (main, Jun  6 2022, 18:49:26) [GCC 12.1.0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd put all your classes in the same file,  it works well:

[image]

When separating the files as you did, we obtain the result that you show. This suggest that it has to do with the import module name.

If you replace the a[bsolute module name](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) with a relative module name:

```
from .Foo import Foo

...
```

Everything works as designed:

[image]

*P.S: I'm not a python expert. So I could not tell if `from Foo` is incorrect and `from .Foo` is the way to go because it's a submodule of the current module, or if this is a pyreverse bug.  But the pyreverse authors are sometimes here, and maybe they can make a statement.  On [this other question on composition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71074140/3723423), the reason was a bug that was expected to be solved in 2.14, but maybe it's a different issue ;-)*

Comment: This is indeed primarily a problem with the import statement. The way it is written in the opening post, module `Bar.py` can only be loaded correctly if Python is invoked from within the directory where `Foo.py` and `Bar.py` are located. Using the relative import you explained would be one way to solve this. Absolute imports would be the other option. Nevertheless as the original example works fine as normal Python code, I opened an issue for this: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/7686

Comment: @dudenr33 Thank you very much for this enlightening feedback.